# Error! cannot create the database connection. / OS X / sqlite3 / python3

Tags: python, macos, sqlite

I'm having some trouble connecting to a sqlite3 database I create in the course of a python script. It's in the same directory as the script, and it's getting created, but the table doesn't get created because it's throwing:

```
Error! cannot create the database connection.
```

...on execution.

Maybe I'm missing something dumb, I don't mess with Python much, but here's the relevant source in case anyone catches something obvious:

```
import sqlite3
from sqlite3 import Error

def db_connect(fDB):
    conn = None
    try:
        conn = sqlite3.connect(fDB)
        print(sqlite3.version)
    except Error as e:
        print(e)
    finally:
        if conn:
            conn.close()

def db_create_table(conn, create_table_sql):
    try:
        c = conn.cursor()
        c.execute(create_table_sql)
    except Error as e:
        print(e)

def db():
    fDB = r"./fDB.db"
    sql_create_fits_table = """ CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS fits (
                                    fHash text PRIMARY KEY,
                                    fType text NOT NULL,
                                    fFocus text NOT NULL,
                                    fSurvey text NOT NULL,
                                    fStart integer NOT NULL,
                                    fEnd integer NOT NULL,
                                    fDuration integer NOT NULL
                                ); """
    # create a database connection
    conn = db_connect(fDB)
    # create tables
    if conn is not None:
        # create fits table
        db_create_table(conn, sql_create_fits_table)
    else:
        print("Error! cannot create the database connection.")

if __name__ == '__main__': # run db operations
    db()
```

Thanks!

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the help on the return, and for the advice on the oo functional method!

Comment: @syzgetic Glad to hear that the answers provided worked. If any answers worked, please consider upvoting them. If you found a specific answer to work best for you, please consider accepting that answer. Doing so will allow future visitors to decide which methods work the best and are best to use in their own code.

Comment: Roger that, just did, thanks for the reminder. I don't have the reputation to be able to upvote yet, but I was able to accept the answer which worked best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason that `conn` is `None` is simply because `db_connect` doesn't have any `return` statement, so the `return` value defaults to `None`. The database connection appears perfectly fine, since you didn't get an error message.

I would recommend using some object oriented programming over functional programming in this case.

```py
import sqlite3

class DBConnection:

    def __init__(self, dbpath):
        self.connection = sqlite3.connect(dbpath)
        self.cursor = self.connection.cursor()

    def create_table(self, query):
        self.cursor.execute(query)

def main():
    dbpath = f"./fDB.db"
    sql_create_fits_table = """
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS fits (
            fHash text PRIMARY KEY,
            fType text NOT NULL,
            fFocus text NOT NULL,
            fSurvey text NOT NULL,
            fStart integer NOT NULL,
            fEnd integer NOT NULL,
            fDuration integer NOT NULL
        ); """
    connection = DBConnection(dbpath)
    connection.create_table(sql_create_fits_table)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not close your connection in the `db_connect` function and you need to return a `conn` from this function as well.

```
def db_connect(fDB):
    conn = None
    try:
        conn = sqlite3.connect(fDB)
        print(sqlite3.version)
    except Error as e:
        print(e)

    return conn
```